# Laravel URL rewrite is not working on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: php, laravel, url-rewriting, ubuntu-18.04

I have probably tried all the solution available online. Still dont understand why URL rewrite is not working for me in this Linode Ubuntu 18.04 VPS.

.htaccess

    
        Options -MultiViews

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

From apache2.conf

```
<Directory /var/www>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

/etc/apache2/sites-available/regenucell.com.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  # Admin email, Server Name (domain name), and any aliases
  ServerAdmin webmaster@regenucell.com
  ServerName  regenucell.com
  ServerAlias regenucell.com  www.regenucell.com

  # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
  DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/regenucell.com/public_html/mms/public
  # Log file locations
  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog  /var/www/html/regenucell.com/log/error.log
  CustomLog /var/www/html/regenucell.com/log/access.log combined
  <Directory "/var/wwwhtml/regenucell.com/public_html/mms/public">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Any clue is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please check mod rewrite is enabled first.

Also check directory directive in your virtual host file www and html is missing/ I believe.